# Error on publishing a Django-CMS 2.4 page

Tags: django, publish, django-cms

I have just updated my site from Django-CMS 2.3 to 2.4, and from Django 1.4.3 to Django 1.5.1.

The site runs fine on my dev environment; at first it gives me the welcome to Django-CMS page (with the pony), and then I just had to run through each page in the admin panel, and press "publish draft" on it to make it appear.

When I tried to repeat the trick on prod though, all goes well until I try to press "publish draft" on the home page. The other pages are ok, but this page gives me the error message:

```
Field 'moderator_state' doesn't have a default value
```

I can preview the page fine, but it won't publish.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Have you followed the [upgrade guide](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0/upgrade/2.4.html). Have you made sure to migrate? The moderator option is no longer in use so I imagine the error originates from that

Comment: Ah - that's it! I've been following that guide several times for a few sites, and I thought I knew it off by heart.  Thank you!  Please put it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look through the [upgrade guide](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.0/upgrade/2.4.html) and make sure to apply DB migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate cms
```

Also, the moderator option is no longer in use so make sure to remove it from the `settings.py`